# Contribution to conductivity of one electron

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrons

Given the speed of electron

$$\vec v = - \gamma \frac{2a}{\hbar} [\sin{(eE_x\frac{a}{\hbar}t)}, 0, 0]$$

inside an electric field

$$\vec E = (E_x, 0, 0)$$

I would like to compute its contribution to the electric conductivity of the material it is in.

---

I have tried to calculate it using Ohm's law:

$$\vec j = \sigma \vec E.$$

The current density for one electron:

$$\vec j = -e\frac{1}{4\pi^3}\vec v = e\frac{1}{4\pi^3}\gamma \frac{2a}{\hbar}[\sin{(eE_x\frac{a}{\hbar}t)}, 0, 0].$$

Using the equation

$$\frac{2a}{\hbar}[\sin{(eE_x\frac{a}{\hbar}t)}, 0, 0] = \sigma (E_x, 0, 0)$$

I have computed the conductivity

$$\sigma = \frac{e}{E_x}\frac{\gamma}{2\pi^3}\frac{a}{\hbar}\sin{(eE_x\frac{a}{\hbar}t)}.$$

However, this is not the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how the problem is exactly meant to be solved, but here's an innocent attempt:

Find the charge density from Maxwell's equation;
$$
\begin{align}
  \nabla\cdot\boldsymbol{\mathrm{E}} &= \dfrac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} %\tag{1}\label{1}
  \\
  &\implies\ \rho = {\epsilon_0}\partial_xE_x %\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}
$$
The general expression for current density is $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{j}} = \rho \boldsymbol{\mathrm{v}}$; so then,
$$
\begin{equation}
  \boldsymbol{\mathrm{j}} = - \frac{\gamma\epsilon_0 2a\partial_x E_x}{\hslash} \sin\left(
      eE_x\dfrac{a}{\hslash}t
    \right) \,\hat{x} %\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation}
$$
As you said yourself, $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{j}} = \sigma \boldsymbol{\mathrm{E}}$; so the conductivity is:
$$
  \sigma = - \frac{\gamma\epsilon_0 2a \partial_x E_x}{\hslash E_x} \sin\left(
      eE_x\dfrac{a}{\hslash}t
    \right) %\tag{4}\label{4}
$$

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the answer is trivial. Since the electron oscillates (the velocity is given by $\sin{(at)}$), the mean velocity of the electron is $\langle \vec v \rangle = (0, 0, 0)$ and it cannot contribute to the conductivity. I think this checks out with @innating's answer if we consider $E_x = \rm  const.$